# $arrayElemAt's first argument must be an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm pulling a set of records from a collection and joining with another collection.

I would like to add a field to the projected field but I'm getting an error - code and error below:

```
db.getCollection("ConnectionEntity").aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
                "Id":"9c06cb0c-966a-4f6b-b087-816587629079"
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $lookup: // Equality Match
            {
                from: "Enterprise",
                localField: "EnterpriseId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "joined"
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {                 
                "Enterprise": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$joined.Profile", 0]}
            }
        },

        // Stage 4 - doesn't work
        {
            $addFields: {
                "Enterprise.Id": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$joined._id", 0]}
            }
        },
    ]
);
```

Error:

```
The following error occurred while attempting to execute the aggregate query

Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 28689: '$arrayElemAt's first argument must be an array'.

The full response is:
{ 

    "_t" : "OKMongoResponse", 

    "ok" : NumberInt(0), 

    "code" : NumberInt(28689), 

    "errmsg" : "$arrayElemAt's first argument must be an array", 

    "$err" : "$arrayElemAt's first argument must be an array"

}
```

Comment: What's the schema behind `ConnectionEntity`?

Comment: you should post your collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `Stage 4` is trying to refer `joined` array which is dropped in `Stage 3` (you're projecting only `Enterprise` field and `_id` implicitly). There are many ways to fix that, for instance you can use `$addFields` in `Stage 4` to keep `joined` array and drop it later:

```
db.ConnectionEntity.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
                "Id":"9c06cb0c-966a-4f6b-b087-816587629079"
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $lookup: // Equality Match
            {
                from: "Enterprise",
                localField: "EnterpriseId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "joined"
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $addFields: {                 
                "Enterprise": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$joined.Profile", 0]}
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $addFields: {
                "Enterprise.Id": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$joined._id", 0]}
            }
        },

        //get rid of joined if it's no longer useful
        {
           $project: {
               joined: 0
           }
        }
    ]
);
```